# Windows Mobile 6.1/6.5 app failing on startup

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6

I have created a small app to backup xml files on a Windows Mobile 6 device. I have created a .lnk file in the startup folder of the device which links to the apps exe. When I restart the device I get this error message 
"The file 'filename' cannot be opened. Either it is not signed with a trusted certificate, or one of its components cannot be found. You might need to reinstall or restore this file."

If I go to the apps installation folder and execute it manually it runs without any issues.

Anyone have any clue as to whats going on or why it is failing at startup?

Comment: How did you create this `.lnk` file? Did your installer put it there?

Answer (score 0):

That might be a problem with your lnk file or the API set is not ready.

There is an API function called IsAPIReady that you can use to delay the startup of your code until the async startup of the OS has loaded all necessary APIs.

If your code uses any DLL or libs, you should ensure that these are loaded either from Windows dir or you specify the full path. If you have DLLs in the app dir, these may not load if the same DLLs are available in Windows dir too. Only a suggestion as the error message is alos shown for DLLs that can not be loaded/found. And, remember, Windows CE based systems do not support a 'current' dir.